# Node js Application- Getting 'command not found' after connecting project to github

Tags: node.js

I made a node js application and I was using nodemon to restart the server whenever I made changes, I made a repository on github and connected my node project. Now I can't run nodemon because it says command not found. I'm not sure about how to fix it.

Comment: You need to clarify your question/problem with the post title.

Comment: Looks like you might not have nodemon installed globally on your computer. What do you get when you run `npm list -g | grep nodemon` from terminal?
If you are running nodemon for a specific project, make sure you are in the project before running `nodemon` and have nodemon module installed in `node_modules/nodemon` directory.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

install nodeman globally and try again, 
hopes you do have configuration file and package.json

npm install nodeman -g